# Sliding scale range

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to code a calculator and I'm struggling with the correct mathematical approach. It's to determine how much profit you can make given the **hours** and **startup cash** available.

The example provided is as follows (lowest range and highest range). How can I turn this into a formula? It seems to be a curve, i.e. the first few hours yield the most, and the more time you spend, the less your profit becomes.

```
Hours: 1
Startup Cash: $10
Potential Profit: $100
Rate: $100 per hour

Hours: 20
Startup Cash: $500
Potential Profit: $1,000
Rate: $50 per hour
```

The user can change the hours and cash between the ranges above. The formula should calculate the Potential Profit given the Hours and Startup Cash.

Comment: I think you're asking us to find a function $f(h,c)=p$ (function of hours and startup cash, equals p.profit) so that $f(1,10) = 100$ and $f(20,500)=100$. But there is an infinity of such functions. This information is not enough to uniquely define the function $f$. I would suggest that you model the case with some mathematical model, in other words come up with some equations of your own.

Comment: That is exactly what I am after. Hours can only be between 1-20 and startup cash can only be between 10 and 500. If you use the minimum of 1 hour and 10 you can make 100 ( so 100 per hour ), and if you use the maximum of 20 hours and $500 you can make 1,000 ( so 50 per hour ). So a function that allows me to build this "sliding scale(?)" depending on hours and cash selected. I would imagine this as a curve on a graph where over time (1 - 20 hours), your profit gets exponentially smaller. If this is even possible to define?

Comment: Exponentially smaller, you say? So there should then be a term in the form $e^{kh}$ with $k<0$. So that's one hint ... How does the startup cash affect the answer?

Comment: I made edits to my answer, but essentially if you spend 1 hour and use 10USD you will make 100USD at a rate of 100USD per hour. At the maximum end, for 20 hours you make 1,000USD at 50USD per hour. I suppose startup cash probably doesn't affect the answer, but it's part of the calculator. So the user would select how many hours they can spend on it, and how much cash they have to start (with the goal of seeing how much profit they can make). Unfortunately my background is web dev only (and high school math many years ago), I know what result I want, it's just the algo that eludes me!

Comment: Maybe the hourly rate should be used instead, i.e. 1 hour = USD100 per hour, 20 hours =USD50 per hour. So a function that fills in the gradual hourly rate decrease between those two ranges.

Comment: One question still. You said that you want the profit per hour to get gradually smaller, and exponentially so. So that means that if you spend infinitely many hours, the profit per hour would be zero, correct? How much would the total profit be if the hours are infinite? (surely, it should be more than 1 000, correct?)

Comment: @ChimeraTheory Welcome to MSE, Chimera Theory!  May I ask why you want to do this?  I ask because (I would assume) contractors set their rates based on some triangulation of what the market will bear and what will meet their needs.  Certainly, there's an element of calculation in this (even if the average person doesn't write down a formula), but it's a complicated calculation based on a lot of factors you haven't given us, and I'm concerned that any function we give you won't (can't!) address your needs.  (But, hey, I could be wrong!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a function that doesn't depend on the startup cash at all? And you want it to be an exponential function on the hours? So in that case I'll assume the form
$$
f(h) = h_0 + h_1 e^{kh}
$$
Where $h_0, h_1$ and $k$ are constants. In addition, we have the boundary conditions
$$
f(1) = 100 \qquad f(20) = 1~000
$$
And in addition, we want $f(0)=0$, which means $h_0+h_1= 0 \Rightarrow h_1 = - h_0$. Now we are left with the equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
h_0 \left(1 - e^{k\times 1} \right) &=& 100 \\
h_0 \left(1 - e^{k\times 20} \right) &=& 1000 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Dividing the equations by each other gives us
$$
\frac{1-e^{20k}}{1-e^{k}} = 10 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad k \approx -0.08544
$$
This was obtained with a numerical method. Now $h_0$ is easy to obtain
$$
h_0 = \frac{100}{1-e^k} = \frac{100}{1-e^{-0.08544}}\approx 1~221.12
$$
Therefore, the answer is
$$
f(h) = (1~221.12) \times (1-e^{-0.08544h})
$$
where $h$ is the hours spent. This function very closely gives the required results.